# Añadir atributos a clase compleja PYTHON

Tags: python, class

Quiero pedir su ayuda para mejorar este código. En este momento tengo la suma, resta, multiplicación, división y valor absoluto, pero también me gustaría añadir la forma conjugada, la polar de un complejo, y que identifica la parte real e imaginaria. Agradecería enormemente su ayuda.

Lo intenté pero no logro que me imprima nada

```
from math import sqrt

class Complex(object):

 def __init__(self, real, imag=0.0):
     self.real = real
     self.imag = imag
     # Formats our results
     print(self.real + self.imag)

 def __add__(self, other):
     print('\nSum:')
     return Complex(self.real + other.real, self.imag + other.imag)

 def __sub__(self, other):
     print('\nDifference:')
     return Complex(self.real - other.real, self.imag - other.imag)
 
 def __mul__(self, other):
     print('\nProduct:')
     return Complex((self.real * other.real) - (self.imag * other.imag),
         (self.imag * other.real) + (self.real * other.imag))

 def __truediv__(self, other):
     print('\nQuotient:')
     r = (other.real**2 + other.imag**2)
     return Complex((self.real*other.real - self.imag*other.imag)/r,
         (self.imag*other.real + self.real*other.imag)/r)

 def __abs__(self):
     print('\nAbsolute Value:')
     new = (self.real**2 + (self.imag**2)*-1)
     return Complex(sqrt(new.real))


i = Complex(2, 10j)
k = Complex(3, 5j)

# Add
i + k
# Subtract
i - k
# Multiply
i * k
# Divide
i / k
# Absolute value
abs(i)
abs(k)
```

De salida me arroja lo siguiente:

```
(3+5j)

Sum:
(5+15j)

Difference:
(-1+5j)

Product:
(56+40j)

Quotient:
(-3.5-2.5j)

Absolute Value:
10.198039027185569

Absolute Value:
5.830951894845301
```

Lo que me gustaría agregar es otro "def" (atributo) que me arroje el conjugado, la forma polar y que también identifique cual es la parte real e imaginaria. No logro que me funcione al intentar agregar esos atributos.

PD: La idea es definir complejos desde cero

Comment: this site is in spanish, trnslate your question please or ask in [StackOverflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que no imprime nada?¿Puedes añadir el código de prueba? Supongo que sabrás que `complex` es un tipo nativo en python.

Comment: Intento añadir otros atributos (def) con lo requerido, sin embargo noto que el código aún no imprime nada, quizá no estoy haciendolo correctamente

Comment: No imprime nada por que no hay un `print()`